# Image_tag - Loading an image from db in rails, using a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, methods, tags

I am trying to show an image from the database in the `show` view. The texts called with @post.display_text all show up alright, just the image is an issue.

When I try:

```
@post.image
```

it shows the following text in my local machine in localhost: 3000/posts/41

```
/system/posts/images/000/000/041/original/imageforpost41.png?1346888720
```

I am trying to display the image itself. I tried:

```
<%= image_tag(@post.image, :size => "80x80", :alt => "Picture") %>
```

The image doesn't show up, only the alt. 
When I tried linking to an image directly it shows it, but not to these in the database per the method used.
What should I do? What is the correct code to display the image?

Comment: The image_tag is used in conjunction with the asset pipeline, Im assuming your not storing the assets in the assets/images folder?.

Comment: no, it is in the database - there is an image for each post. this is the `show` view, and so a specific image is relevant for this show (with the relevant ID)

Comment: So your just storing the image location in the db, so where is the image on the filesystem

Comment: As I wrote in the question - when I output the image location as text it comes out as: `/system/posts/images/000/000/041/original/imageforpost41.png?1346888720`. does this help?

Comment: This is all dev on my local machine. The live dev and production servers are in aws. Does this mean that it will work when it is on the remote machine?

Comment: The image_tag will look in /assets/images/ locally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28261/discussion-between-nathan-willoughby-and-lucy-weatherford)

Comment: Okay, I'm there. I also tried `<img src=<%= @post.image %> >` and it didn't work either.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= image_tag "http://abc.com#{@post.image}" %>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use below:

```
<%= image_tag(@post.image.filename, :size => "80x80", :alt => "Picture", :width => '100', :height =>'100') %>
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and what I did? It didn't work.. I don't have the specific filename, I get it through the `@post.image` method

Comment: Have you used height and width parameters?